# NuxtJS - vee-validate doesn't return custom message

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vee-validate

vee-validate.js

```
import { extend } from 'vee-validate'
import * as rules from 'vee-validate/dist/rules'

const phone = {
  getMessage (field) {
    return `The ${field} must be a valid phone number`
  },
  validate (value) {
    const PhoneNumber = require('awesome-phonenumber')
    const pn = new PhoneNumber(value)
    return pn.isValid()
  }
}

extend('phone', phone)
```

usage in component:

```
 <ValidationProvider v-slot="{ errors }" rules="required|phone">
    <input
      v-model="number"
      placeholder="Ex. +13198832832"
      type="tel"
      name="phonenumber"
      label="Phone Number*"
      />
      <ValidationDisplay :message="errors[0]" />
 </ValidationProvider>
```

For some reason the validation message is always:
`{field} is not valid.` rather then what I assigned it to be.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a field name on the `ValidationProvider` component.  This is what is used in the error messages.

```
<ValidationProvider v-slot="{ errors }" rules="required|phone" name="Phone Number">
    <input
      v-model="number"
      placeholder="Ex. +13198832832"
      type="tel"
      name="phonenumber"
      label="Phone Number*"
      />
      <ValidationDisplay :message="errors[0]" />
 </ValidationProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

For future Google travelers such as myself

To fix this you need to replace `getMessage` with `message`

So you should endup with

```
  message: field => {
    return `The ${field} must be a valid phone number`
  },
```